# Having trouble with show/hide/visible in VB .net It only works the first time

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a multi form application I'm close to finishing, but I have a HUGE problem.
I need to keep a main form open, basically a communications task, that opens other forms that display general status and asks for various user input. The problem is that when any form is requested either automatically by the status from the communications engine, or via user button press.  The first time a form is requested there is no problem, however the second time any given form is requested, it shows on the windows task bar, but will not open on the screen.  All form switching in this application is handled by the same routine. 
NOTE: The form named "WEDGE_MENU_SCREEN" is the form that stays open and active, only one other form should be active at any time.
Here is the code.

```
 Public Function GoToForm(Requested_form As Form) As Boolean
    'in a multi form app, we only want ONE form active on screen at any given time.
    'all screen change requests should come from the same operating thread
    Dim Not_found_form As Boolean = True
    '        Dim frm As Form
    Dim formNames As New List(Of String)
    Dim xformNames As New List(Of String)

    'get a list of active forms running under this main thread LESS the static one
    For Each currentForm As Form In Application.OpenForms
        If currentForm.Name <> "WEDGE_MENU_SCREEN" Then
            formNames.Add(currentForm.Name)
        End If
    Next
    'from that list create another less the requested in the case that the requested form is already up
    For Each currentFormName As String In formNames
        If currentFormName <> Requested_form.Name Then
            xformNames.Add(currentFormName)
        End If
    Next
    'if the second list is not empty
    If xformNames.Count > 0 Then
        'hide all active forms in the second list
        For Each currentFormName As String In xformNames
            Application.OpenForms(currentFormName).Visible = False
            Application.OpenForms(currentFormName).Opacity() = 0
        Next
    End If

    'then activate the requested form
    Requested_form.Visible = True
    Requested_form.Opacity = 1
    Return True
End Function
```

FURTHER NOTE: I have tried the following as well
   Application.OpenForms(currentFormName).Hide()
   with Requested_form.Show()
ALSO
   Application.OpenForms(currentFormName).Close()
   with Requested_form.Show()

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
-Jim

Comment: I suggest storing the forms in a `Dictionary(Of String, Form)` with the name being the Key and the Form being the Value. That way you don't need to iterate all the forms every time you want to show one. You can also use Form.Show() every time instead of changing the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you make the logic a bit simpler it would help. The 3 loop can be combined into one.

```
For Each currentForm As Form In Application.OpenForms
    If currentForm.Name <> "WEDGE_MENU_SCREEN" AndAlso currentForm.Name <> Requested_form.Name Then
        currentForm.Visible = False
        currentForm.Opacity() = 0
    End If
Next
```